# Putting fence around sheep

Tags: computational-geometry

[Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) algorithms are well known. However, in my case, the goal is slightly modified:

Given $N$ points in a plane, construct convex polygon with minimal area so that it contains all points, and there is no point that is closer than given distance $d$ from polygon edges, and number of vertices of such polygon is the same as number of vertices of the convex hull of given points.

In other words, given $N$ sheep:

[image]

... find the fence:

[image]

(Sheep can be considered points, but $d$ is still greater than $0$.)

Comment: Interesting problem. Notice that finding the convex hull of disks centered at the sheep is not necessarily optimal.

Comment: Probably inflating the convex hull would help?

Comment: @lisyarus Right, that was my first version, in short: find centroid than "inflate" convex hull by moving convex hull edges away from the centroid. However, I was not able to prove that is a correct method.

Comment: @VividD I didn't mean centroid. You can inflate edges by distance $d$ along their normals. Computing it is some kind of straight skeleton, but it's not obvious for me that the area would be minimal =(

Comment: Suppose $d=1$. Put four sheep at $(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-0.01)$, and $(0,100)$. Then the inflated convex hull is certainly not optimal $-$ you can do better by truncating the hull at $y=101$ and merging the two lower edges into one.

Comment: The following paper describes the convex hull problem where you have discs instead of points, maybe it can be useful to you even if it does not directly solve your problem: RAPPAPORT, David. A convex hull algorithm for discs, and applications. *Computational Geometry*, 1992, 1.3: 171-187. http://ac.els-cdn.com/092577219290015K/1-s2.0-092577219290015K-main.pdf?_tid=caf266de-075b-11e4-9595-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1404905335_262bfe9a1c5709d46ffe30f517a11bbf

Comment: @uvts_cvs, that's great info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can take some ideas from the following paper

[RAPPAPORT, David. A convex hull algorithm for discs, and applications. *Computational Geometry*, 1992, 1.3: 171-187.](http://ac.els-cdn.com/092577219290015K/1-s2.0-092577219290015K-main.pdf?_tid=caf266de-075b-11e4-9595-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1404905335_262bfe9a1c5709d46ffe30f517a11bbf)

where you model each sheep with a circle of radius $d$.

However the paper does not directly solve your problem because
the convex hull described in the paper is composed by line segments and arcs of a circle.

Comment: This is very close to the answer, and there is no better, so I will mark it as an answer. Thanks for great info!